# Polars replacing the first n rows with certain values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-polars

In Pandas we can replace the first `n` rows with certain values:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"test": np.arange(0, 10)})
df.iloc[0:5] = np.nan
df

out:
   test
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   5.0
6   6.0
7   7.0
8   8.0
9   9.0
```

What would be the equivalent operations in `Python Polars`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.with_row_index()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_index.html#polars-dataframe-with-row-index):

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"test": np.arange(1, 11)})

print(
    df.with_row_index()
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("index") < 5)
        .then(None)
        .otherwise(pl.col("test"))
        .alias("test")
    )
    .drop("index")
)
```

Prints:

```
shape: (10, 1)
┌──────┐
│ test │
│ ---  │
│ f64  │
╞══════╡
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ 6    │
│ 7    │
│ 8    │
│ 9    │
│ 10   │
└──────┘
```

or by `pl.int_range()` which gives more flexibility in cases of groups.

```py
print(
(df
 .with_columns(
    pl.int_range(0, pl.len(), dtype=pl.UInt32).over(True).alias("index")
    )
 .with_columns(
     pl.when(pl.col("index") < 5)
     .then(None)
     .otherwise(pl.col("test"))
     .alias("test")
     )
 .drop("index")
 )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this oneliner:

```
df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.int_range(0, pl.len()) >= 5).then("test"))
```

Comment: Also if the 'certain value' is not None/Null this could be extended to use any replacement value using: `df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.int_range(0, pl.len()) < 5).then(None).otherwise('test').alias('test'))`

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here's a couple of more possible solutions.

This one works for `null` only, unless your fill the nulls later. So we just shift the column up and then shift it back down, leaving top `n` rows empty:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('test').shift(-5).shift(5))

┌──────┐
│ test │
│ ---  │
│ f64  │
╞══════╡
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ 6    │
│ 7    │
│ 8    │
│ 9    │
│ 10   │
└──────┘
```

Another one creates a new column out of the given value repeated `n` and then we use [`append()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.append.html) to concat with [`tail()`] of the existing column:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.repeat(None, 5).append(pl.col('test').tail(df.count() - 5))
)

┌──────┐
│ test │
│ ---  │
│ f64  │
╞══════╡
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ Null │
│ 6    │
│ 7    │
│ 8    │
│ 9    │
│ 10   │
└──────┘
```

I did a quick performance check with `timeit` and it looks like the one with `with_row_index` is the fastest of all:

```py
%timeit df.with_row_index().with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("index") < 5).then(None).otherwise(pl.col("test")).alias("test")).drop("index")
65.3 µs ± 3.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit df.with_columns(pl.repeat(None, 5).append(pl.col('test').tail(df.count() - 5)))
286 µs ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.int_range(0, pl.len()) >= 5).then("test"))
140 µs ± 20.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit df.with_columns(pl.col('test').shift(-5).shift(5))
142 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

It's also possible to turn the solution with `with_row_index` around to make it a bit more concise (again, only if you want `null` as your replacement value):

```py
(
    df.with_row_index()
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("index") >= 5).then(pl.col("test"))
    ).drop("index")
)
```