# Polars Customized Expression Constructor Function

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, python-polars

I want to change the first `n` rows with certain values in Polars. The normal use case is solved in the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143771/polars-replacing-the-first-n-rows-with-certain-values).

However, I want to achieve this by constructing a customized function:

```py
from polars.type_aliases import IntoExpr, IntoExprColumn
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({"test": np.arange(1, 11)})

def _func(x: IntoExpr) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.when((x+1) < 5).then(None).otherwise(x+1)

df.with_columns(
    _func(pl.col("test")).alias("test+1")
    )
```

1. How to I create the index col using the customized function? (**by not making the Polars DataFrame as an input parameter**)
2. Is there anyway to access the Polars DataFrame that the Polars Expression is used for by not passing in the DataFrame as an input parameter?

Comment: Regarding the index column: You could use `pl.int_range(pl.len())` as index column.

Comment: @Hericks Thanks now the first question is solved. However I have another question. Say I define the helper as `helper = pl.int_range(pl.len())` and use it multiple times throughout the function. According to Polars's Lazy execution. How would the query optimization be compared to use plain `pl.int_range(pl.len())` multiple times throughout the query?

Comment: It caches expressions that you use more than once so that it doesn't actually calculate them multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that we cannot access `Polars.DataFrame` object from `Polars Expressions` without passing them in as input params.

However, we could use the following queries to

1. Replace the `n`th value with the average of the first `n` values
2. Set `1-n`th value, left inclusive, to `Null`
3. Original value otherwise

```py
def query(
    target_var: IntoExpr = pl.col("var"),
    index_col: IntoExpr | pl.Expr | None = None,
    n: int = 1,
    **kwargs,
    ) -> pl.Expr:
    
    if "index_col" in kwargs:
        index_col = kwargs.pop("index_col") # IntoExpr
    else:
        index_col = pl.int_range(0, pl.len())

    mean_nth = pl.head(target_var.meta.output_name(), n).mean()
    expr = (
        pl.when(index_col == (n-1))
            .then(mean_nth)
            .when(index_col < (n-1))
            .then(None)
            .otherwise(target_var)
            )
    
    return expr
```